# Set custom description for sharing a facebook page url via Facebook Connect API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problem using FB api to post feed on friend's wall.

When I assign `link` parameter with a facebook app url (`link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/12345'`), all `{picture, name, description}` are displayed as I provided. However, if `link` parameter assigned with a facebook page, all of custom parameters are overridden by the description of that facebook page.

```
var post = {
                access_token: acc,
                to:fId[p],
                link:'https://www.facebook.com/Sony',
                picture:'https://picture.com/abc.png',
                name:"I love sony",
                description: data.name+" has invited you to love sony",
            };
```

What I want to do is still showing custom description and picture even I'm sharing a facebook page to friends' wall. Here is the snippet of my posting code:

```
                    FB.api("/"+fId[p]+"/feed",'post',post,function(response){
                        if (!response || response.error) {
                 console.log(response.error);
                        } else {
                             console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Found out the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577723/facebook-php-share-api-issue) but no answer yet.

Comment: If Facebook actively decides to ignore the parameters in this case – then maybe they just don’t _want_ you to be able to do that …? That’d be my guess – if you’d like to see that confirmed (or denied), you should open a bug report with Facebook.